# How much does it cost to build a Boeing 737 NG?

Tags: airliner, boeing-737

I don't mean how much is the list price. I am asking how much does it cost for Boeing to buy the engine, wing, etc. and put it together and ship it. What is the total cost of ordering everything and putting it together?

Comment: _Buy_ the engine, wing etc??? What about the RnD for all these? It's not that simple as "purchasing" the items. Someone needs to develop them and sometimes they are developed for the specific project. And what about parts transportation?

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis This is what I meant by etc. meaning other parts.

Comment: It is a reasonable economic question to assess the cost of production of the next plane. The jargon would be the marginal cost of production.

Comment: It is hard to determine the cost, regardless the price change of raw material, other cost may vary when time past.

Comment: Using different accounting standard like GAAP or IFRS may show different cost; as well as adopting different accounting principle.

Comment: This is asking for guesses & opinions.  Nobody who has anything close to authentic figures for what it costs Boeing is going to be posting anything that even looks or sounds like a number on a site like this.  Even setting aside the myriad of ways that you account for the costs that are "per assembly line" rather than "per airframe," real numbers like this are highly sensitive & Boeing keeps data like this *highly* confidential.

Comment: This question is quite hard to answer. Many commercial data are confidential. You may estimate separately R&D (spent once), raw materials (variyng in time, even between purchase by Boeing, beginning of assembly, end of aircraft's assembly, livery to cosutmer and payment), building or retrofit cost.

Comment: Ralph is correct. Also, the _marginal_ cost of building one 737 would be quite misleading, since a lot of the cost of building almost any aircraft comes from the one-time R&D and certification costs. Those are well into the billions of dollars for a new airliner these days. Even the R&D and certification costs of updating an existing family of airliners is often well in the billions today.